# For an alertController: what is the sourceView of a selected segment in a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an `UISegmentedControl` with 4 segments. Some of these segments instantiate an `UIAlertController` when selected by the user.

On the `UIAlertController`, you can set `popoverPresentationController?.sourceView` to let the alert controller point to the view of origin, which will be used on larger devices like an iPad.

I try to pass the `UISegmentedControl`, which works, but the anchor is always the top left corner of the segmented control - not the segment that was selected.

I'd like to use the actual segment of the `UISegmentedControl` as a sourceView, but there is no array on `UISegmentedControl` that contains the segments.

There is a subviews property that holds an array of views. The number corresponds to the number of segments, so I though I found my solution. But if I assign:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = segmentedControl.subviews[2]
```

...for the 3rd segment, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. It looks like this array is not always in the order of segments on the screen.

How can I find the correct subview to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (segmentedControl.subviews.sorted { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x })[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
```

This will first sort the views in the order of their x coordinate. Then I can use the `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` as an index.

Comment: This is dangerous code that could easily break in a future update to iOS. Never make assumptions about the private subview layout of a view you have no control over.

Comment: So how would you do that?

Comment: At a minimum, write the code in a way that won’t crash when segments are no longer the direct subviews of the control.

Comment: You mean checking if there are indeed 4 subviews if the segmented control has 4 segments, in order to prevent the array index from crashing the app? The rest are non-optional properties of the views? Any more concrete ideas?